# How to set bounds on a plotspace in CorePlot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I am trying to draw multiple scatter plots on the same graph using Core-Plot. They have the same x-axis (time), but I want them to be drawn independently of each other. For eg, for two plots, I want the screen to be divided into two parts, the upper part showing one plot and the lower part showing the other (I intend to ultimately plot a real-time multi-channel input). Something like this:
[image: Image only used for representational purposes]

I tried modifying the tutorial given in the following link to use two plotspaces instead of one:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2

However, there is no function to set the bounds of a plotspace. The functions xRange and yRange change the range of the axes, but both the plotspaces still occupy the whole screen.

Following is a code snippet that shows two ways in which I tried to accomplish setting bounds:

```
-(void)configurePlots {

//Get graph and plot space
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
CPTXYPlotSpace *aaplPlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

//**Setting xRange and yRange doesn't work**

aaplPlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(0.0)
                                                            length:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(graph.bounds.size.width)];
aaplPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(0.0)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat((graph.bounds.size.height)/3)];



CPTXYPlotSpace *googPlotSpace = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
googPlotSpace.xRange = aaplPlotSpace.xRange;
googPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat((graph.bounds.size.height)/3)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat((graph.bounds.size.height)/3)];


[graph addPlotSpace:googPlotSpace];


//Create Plots

//**Trying to set bounds using initWithFrame doesn't work either**

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, graph.bounds.size.width, graph.bounds.size.height/2);
CPTScatterPlot *aaplPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
aaplPlot.dataSource = self;
aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;
CPTColor *aaplColor = [CPTColor redColor];
[graph addPlot:aaplPlot toPlotSpace:aaplPlotSpace];

rect = CGRectMake(0.0, graph.bounds.size.height/2, graph.bounds.size.width, graph.bounds.size.height/2);
CPTScatterPlot *googPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
googPlot.dataSource = self;
googPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolGOOG;
CPTColor *googColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
[graph addPlot:googPlot toPlotSpace:googPlotSpace];
//[graph addPlot:googPlot];

//Set up Plot space
[aaplPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aaplPlot]];
CPTMutablePlotRange *xaRange = [aaplPlotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
[xaRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
aaplPlotSpace.xRange = xaRange;
CPTMutablePlotRange *yaRange = [aaplPlotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
[yaRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)];
aaplPlotSpace.yRange = yaRange;

//Create styles and symbols

CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplLineStyle = [aaplPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
aaplLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
aaplLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
aaplPlot.dataLineStyle = aaplLineStyle;
CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
aaplSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
CPTPlotSymbol *aaplSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
aaplSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:aaplColor];
aaplSymbol.lineStyle = aaplSymbolLineStyle;
aaplSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
aaplPlot.plotSymbol = aaplSymbol;

CPTMutableLineStyle *googLineStyle = [googPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
googLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
googLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
googPlot.dataLineStyle = googLineStyle;
CPTMutableLineStyle *googSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
googSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
CPTPlotSymbol *googSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol starPlotSymbol];
googSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:googColor];
googSymbol.lineStyle = googSymbolLineStyle;
googSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
googPlot.plotSymbol = googSymbol;
}
```

My question is, is my current approach correct in trying to set bounds on plotspaces or do I need to draw different graphs on the same screen and set the bounds on the graphs? And how do I set bounds on plotspaces or graphs (whichever is the right way!)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're wanting the plot spaces separated, I'd draw multiple graphs on the same screen or different screens for iPhone since screen real estate is so limited.  That being said, keep in mind that one plot space can have more than one array of plots. Our graph has multiple real time line plots all within the same plot space. I don't think this would work if we were using different types of graphs thought.  But it sounds like you're just trying to do 2 (or more) scatter/line plots.

Comment: Also, the bounds are set in the first part of that demo. See the "Meet the Host" section about 60% down this page: [Core Plot, part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1), or if you're in the code in the demo project look at the configureHost function.  CPTGraphHostingView contains the CPTGraph(s) which contain(s) the CPTPlotSpace(s).  You should definitely look into the CorePlotGallery sample project (specifically CompositePlot) that is included in the download.

Comment: Yes, the configureHost function does define the bounds, but they are of the CPTGraphHostingView and not the plotspace. Anyway, I am going ahead with that as that seems to work. Thanks for the advice and for pointing me in the right direction with CompositePlot and configureHost.

Comment: I apologize.  All of the examples and projects I've used this in, I've just sized the hosting view to what I want and then assigned the same frame to the graph. You can assign different boundaries in configureGraph.  If by bounds of the plotSpace you mean you want to define the min/max values of the x and y axes, then you need to set those with plotSpace.xRange and yRange.